# Android: Progress Bar as a place holder

Tags: android, progress-bar

I was hoping to figure out how to use a progress bar spinner to be a place holder while my image is being fetched. I put an animated .gif in but soon after I found out that .gif don't play nice with android. Here is my code now:

```
public void displayImage(String url, CarActivity activity, ImageView imageView) {
        if(imageMap.containsKey(url))
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageMap.get(url));
        else {
            queueImage(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);

        }
    }
```

Instead of setting the image to my loading.gif how can I use the built in spinner as a place holder and possibly have it overlaid on another image.

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your real question is "how can I have one View placed above another View". In your case, it seems you want an ImageView in the back and a ProgressBar in the front. (The ProgressBar name is a bit unintuitive because by default it's not a bar, it's a small spinning animation).

In your layout, where you currently have your ImageView, create a RelativeLayout. Within the RelativeLayout, first place your ImageView, and then place your ProgressBar. Set the ProgressBar's android:visibility attribute = "invisible", and when you want it to be seen, set it visible within your code: view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); (or .INVISIBLE).

Set the RelativeLayout's size to wrap_content, and do the same for the ImageView. For the ProgressBar, you may wish to hard code a small size, say 40dip width and also height. Set the layout parameters of the ProgressBar to "centerInParent" if you want it centered over the middle of the image.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using a [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html) to switch between your ImageView and a ProgressBar widget.

Add the ViewAnimator to your XML Layout, and then do something like this in your Activity:

```
ViewAnimator switch = (ViewAnimator) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
ProgressBar loading = new ProgressBar(this);

switch.addView(loading, 0, myLayoutParams);
switch.addView(image, 1, myLayoutParams);
```

Where the first field of addView() is the Child View you are adding, the second is it's index in the Animator, and the third is a LayoutParams object that you have defined (which I didn't show).

I haven't tested the code, but that should hopefully display the Android ProgressBar widget.

Then, whenever your image has loaded, call:

```
switch.showNext();
```

Also, the example [here](http://www.ctctlabs.com/index.php/blog/detail/android_dont_overlook_viewswitcher/) seems to be similar to what you need if you want to check it out.

Comment: After posting this, I realized that @mah came up with a much simpler solution.  I would try that one first.